# Is there a way to specify a projection for ndb.get_multi()?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Using NDB, it is possible to specify a [projection](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#projection) for a query, allowing to limit the number of properties that are retrieved for the entities that match the query.

However, I couldn't find anything in the documentation about how to specify a projection when using `ndb.get_multi()`, which always fetches complete entities.

Is there a way to fetch only certain properties when using `ndb.get_multi()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the projection feature only works for queries.  There would be no advantage (in terms of fewer I/O operations) to projecting get() operations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you elaborate a bit more on why projecting is helpful in queries but not in get operations?

Comment: In queries, a projection satisfies the values straight from the index, so the datastore backend can avoid reading the actual entity entirely.  That's a big win as it saves real disk seeks.  For get operations, all you have is the key, so you can't avoid reading the actual entity -- the only saving you'd get would be deserialization cost and some bandwidth, which usually doesn't amount to much.

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up in a situation where using projection with `ndb.get_multi()` did result in performance improvements. I have a large entity class with ~25 properties, some of which are even repeated. I need to get_by_id about 10 of these objects for serving each web page in my app, but I only need 4 properties per object. If I implement this using plain `ndb.get_multi()`, then around half the frontend CPU time ends up being spent in an NDB API method named `Model._from_pb`, i.e. deserializing the objects that were read from the database. This looks like something that might be improved with projection, and indeed, in my case using projection the below way have cut the overall response time by half:

```
Product.query(Product.key.IN(keys_to_get)).fetch(projection=list_of_columns)
```

Where `Product` is the name of my entity class. Of course in this case a new index is needed for the query.

Comment: just to clarify, are you saying you managed to implement the above or are you saying that this is a use-case that would benefit from being able to combine get_multi and projection queries?

Comment: Actually, I was trying to say both of those. I do have a part in my program where I need to get multiple entities by ID, but only a few fields are interesting. That is my use case that would benefit from combining get_multi with projections.The other thing I was trying to say is that I have actually managed to emulate get_multi() with projections using the above code snippet. It actually works for me in GAE Python 2 for my use case and it's actually faster than using get_multi().