# Google app engine: Cost and efficiency of retrieving entities using keys vs using queries

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have read in various places that:

> projection queries run faster and cost less than one that returns
>   complete entities

because the query results are satisfied from the indexes rather than disk reads.
See:[Google docs here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/retrieving-query-results) and [Comment from Guido Van Rossum here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936904/is-there-a-way-to-specify-a-projection-for-ndb-get-multi).

The comments from Guido seem to imply that it is faster to retrieve an entity's details through a projection query than through a key.

However, Pg 135 of 'Programming GAE with Python' by Dan Sanderson mentions:

> if you have a key...you can retrieve the entity quickly, much more quickly than with a datastore query.

Given a situation where i can retrieve my data using either a projection query or the entities' key (with get_multi):

1. Is it faster to use the keys or the projection queries?
2. Is one method more expensive than the other?

Comment: From Guido answer from the part "in terms of fewer I/O operations) " I can understand that they are the same. With an exception of bandwidth as he said. About your second question you can check the bullets from the [pricing doc](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing).

Answer (score 0):

The advise is consistent.  I'll try to clarify.

1. If you have a key, fetch an entity with that
2. If you don't have a key AND you can solve you problem with a projection, use that
3. If you don't have a key, need full entity(s), then use a query that returns full entities

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and sorry for being pedantic but based on your answer, the answer to Part 1 of my question is in fact that retrieving by Keys and get_multi is faster than a projection query correct?

Comment: Projection queries and fetching full entities have different use cases.    Projection queries give you parts of an entity, require all fields to be in a single index, and you won't be able to write back an entity if you fetch the partial fields with a projection.  Fetching by keys gives you full entities that could then be written back.